# MinGW Compiler process returns process return 0xC00000fd

Tags: c, mingw

I m trying to implement a binary search tree in C .. I m using codeblocks ide with MinGW compiler

When i m trying to run the following code i this runtime erro
*process returns process return 0xC00000fd*

But when i compile at http://ideone.com/
it works fine with out any errors

Solved : thanks to @user1161318

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *parent;
    int value;
}*r;

void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    int sam;
    if(root)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        sam = root->value;
        printf(" %d ->",sam);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

void insert(struct node *root,int x)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->value = x;
    struct node *y=root;
    while(root)
    {
        y = root;
        if(root->value > x)
        {
            root = root->left;
        }
        else
        {
            root = root->right;
        }
    }
    temp->parent = y;
    if(!y)
    {
        r=temp;
    }
    else if(x > y->value)
    {
        y->right = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        y->left = temp;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        insert(r,i);
    }
    inorder(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0xc00000fd` is "stack overflow". Run your program under the debugger to see why the overflow is occurring.

Comment: There's one thing here that's a bit of a red flag... you aren't setting your left and right to NULL when you allocate, yet you are using that as a condition in while (root) ...

Comment: @RaymondChen it works fine in the debugger , no error thrown .. I m getting the error when i "build and run"

Comment: Then use the post-mortem debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Global variable `struct node *r` is not initialized in `main()`.

Comment: I tried that one too ...
I added r=NULL; in the first line of main .. Still its not working

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with a fortran program, and it went away when I disabled OpenMP in the compiler settings.  Since compiling and running your program somewhere else worked, you might have the same or a similar problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).